# Dashboard doesn't work propertly

Tags: errors, dashboard, performance

I have strange issue with Wordpress on my server. After installing WP, some sites of admin panel require over 3-4 minutes to load. There are these "some" :

- `Plugins`
- `Themes`
- `Dashoboard main site`
- `Import`

Posts are also loaded inpropertly.
It's very confusing because ONLY for these sites errors occur. It doesn't seem to be a server configuration problem because the same server manage with other websites (Joomla etc.) . It's really fast as well as conncetion from ISP.

**The question is**: Is there something (missing) in `wp-config.php` , `wp-setting.php` or other files that might caused such a bizzare slow of loaded pages? What about server configuration?

I set up a new WP so there is no plugins or other stuff installed. Memory limit is set to 128MB. Page analyzers show long time for redirect from /wp-admin to /wp-admin/ and  connection errors to mysite.com/wp-admin. (without details). Google PageSpeed Insights show me timeout so I suppose that others analyzers mean the same.

Any help would be appreciate. Thank you in advance! :)

**UPDATE**

I looked at database and some variables at summaration and there are lots of records that
I am worry about. I am not sure is this caused by Wordpress or server configuration is guilty but that is what i have spotted:

Handler_read_rnd    **29 M**

Handler_read_rnd_next   **172 M**

Qcache_lowmem_prunes    **103 k**

Created_tmp_disk_tables **147 k**

Select_range_check  **19 k**

Opened_tables   **12 k**

Select_full_join    **2 296**

Table_locks_waited  **930**

There is nothing beside Wordpress on server. So in database

Comment: "couple connection errors". What connections exactly? (in an [edit] please)

Comment: This sounds like an underpowered/overloaded server to me, but there  is too little information to be sure. As kaiser asked, "What connections exactly?"

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking about :). Connections to /wp-admin. It seems to be underpowered/overloaded but it's not. And here's a problem